# sf map add missing values with inter_join

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, r-sf

I have a technical question for you please.

```
    read_sf("map.shp")  %>% mutate(Groups = as.factor(Groups)) %>% 
        mutate(Groups = factor(Groups, levels = c(paste0(1:23)))) %>%
        left_join(data, by = "cities_code") %>%
# Show map with cities border
      ggplot() +
        geom_sf(aes(fill = Groups),  size = 0.4) +
# Color the different Groups, here 23 colors
        stat_sf_coordinates(aes(size = observation)) +
# Put point with the size of my number of observations
        scale_radius(range = c(1, 6)) +
        geom_sf(fill = "transparent", color = "gray20", size = 1, data = . %>% group_by(Groups) %>% summarise()) +
# Show the border of my Groups
        theme_bw()
```

This map represents exactly what I want. It represent cities of one state subdivided by district ("Groups"). But between my `map.shp` and my `data` I have a difference of 50 cities, because there is no observation in these cities (so no point of "`stat_sf_coordinates(aes(size = observation))`").

I can find the difference with `anti_join(data, by = "cities_code")`. 
I would like to have the same map but with the missing cities colored in red please please.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please include a `dput` of a sample of your data, perhaps with just a few cities?

Comment: My data look like that : `data <- structure(list(Cities_code = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13
), observation = c(13L, 11L, 447L, 23L, 252L, 76L, 1905L, 49L, 
1173L, 217L), Groups = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")` . And in my `map.shp` I have all the cities code 1:lenght(cities), here : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13..

Comment: I want add something like this into my code : `read_sf("map.shp")  %>%  
  anti_join(data, by = "cities_code") %>% 
  ggplot() +geom_sf(aes(fill = "red"), color = "red", lwd =1, size = 0.8) + theme(legend.position = "none")`. Thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple :

```
        read_sf("map.shp")  %>% mutate(Groups = as.factor(Groups)) %>% 
            mutate(Groups = factor(Groups, levels = c(paste0(1:23)))) %>%
            left_join(data, by = "cities_code") %>%
          ggplot() +
            geom_sf(aes(fill = Groups),  size = 0.4) +
            stat_sf_coordinates(aes(size = observation)) +
            scale_radius(range = c(1, 6)) +
##

geom_sf(fill = "red", color = "gray40", size = 0.4, data = . %>% anti_join(data, by = "cities_code")) +

##
            geom_sf(fill = "transparent", color = "gray20", size = 1, data = . %>% group_by(Groups) %>% summarise()) +
            theme_bw()
```

Comment: Would anyone know how to add a legend to my new line of code, please? With a red square with marked "no_obs". Thx!